# React Native doesn't respect the function scope

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-functional-component

I am developing a react-native app. Recently, I encountered a strange behavior of functional components. Typically, I break large component into smaller components, write separate logic for each smaller component, and then call them in the same component.

In the below code, I have not defined the method `onPressed` in the `SmallComponentB` but when I click on this it calls the method from `SmallComponentA`

```
const SmallComponentA = ({}) => {

    onPressed = () => alert('Clicked A')

    return <Text onPress={onPressed} >Press On A</Text>
}

const SmallComponentB = ({}) => {
    return <Text onPress={onPressed} >Press On B</Text>
}

const ActualComponent = ({}) => {
    return(
        <>
        <SmallComponentA />
        <SmallComponentB />
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: That's because you are creating a global variable. You must be using sloppy mode (as opposed to strict). Change your code `const onPressed = () => alert('Clicked A')`and you'll get the expected behavior.

Comment: @RuanMendes Yes, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it both ways, either it's a separate function in each or it should be a common function

With Separate:

```
    const SmallComponentA = ({}) => {
        const onPressed = () => alert('Clicked A')
    
        return <Text onPress={onPressed} >Press On A</Text>
    }
    
    const SmallComponentB = ({}) => {
        const onPressed = () => alert('Clicked B')
    
        return <Text onPress={onPressed} >Press On B</Text>
    }
    
    const ActualComponent = ({}) => {
        return(
            <>
            <SmallComponentA />
            <SmallComponentB />
            </>
        )
    }
```

Common Function:

```
    const onPressed = ( component ) => alert('Common Clicked '+ component);
    
    const SmallComponentA = ({}) => {
      return <Text onPress={()=>onPressed("A")}>Press On A</Text>;
    };
    
    const SmallComponentB = ({}) => {
      return <Text onPress={()=>onPressed("B")}>Press On B</Text>;
    };
    
    const ActualComponent = ({}) => {
      return (
        <>
          <SmallComponentA />
          <SmallComponentB />
        </>
      );
    };
```

Hope it will hep you!

Comment: Yes, by adding a const keyword it works fine.

For your second approach - We should avoid an arrow function inside the render method because the arrow function returns a new function every time. This causes React to think something has changed in our view, when in fact nothing has.

Answer (score -1):

So you can individually set the onPressed function inside each of the individual arrow function like,

```js
const SmallComponentA = ({}) => {
    const onPressed = () => alert('Clicked A');

    return <Text onPress={onPressed}>Press On A</Text>;
}

const SmallComponentB = ({}) => {
    const onPressed = () => alert('Clicked B');

    return <Text onPress={onPressed}>Press On B</Text>;
}

const ActualComponent = ({}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <SmallComponentA />
            <SmallComponentB />
        </>
    );
}
```